# Step into -[NSInvocation invoke] during debugging

Tags: objective-c, debugging, lldb, nsinvocation

When debugging Objective-C code, lldb skips calls to objc_msgSend and stops in the actual method being called.

I'd like to have similar behavior when debugging some code that uses `NSInvocation`. When reaching the point where `-[NSInvocation invoke]` is called, I'd like to make a 'step-in' command and skip `objc_msgSend`, `-[NSInvocation invoke]`, `__invoking___` and `objc_msgSend` and land on the actual method.

Are there some LLDB settings that can be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

lldb doesn't have native support for NSInvocation.

If you're so inclined, please file a bug about this.  Since it's ObjC specific, probably better to file it with http://bugreporter.apple.com.

Comment: Reported as https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6097195182850048.

Meanwhile, I'm gonna investigate if this can be achived by writing custom thread plan for LLDB using Python bindings. See http://lldb.llvm.org/python-reference.html "USING THE PYTHON API'S TO CREATE CUSTOM STEPPING LOGIC". Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That should be possible.  If you have any questions, the lldb-dev list is probably the best resource:  lldb-dev@lists.llvm.org.  One of the limitations of the SB implemented stepping plans is that you can't currently call functions in a thread plan.  I can't tell off-hand if you will need to do that or not, however.